# Customer Search with data from database

Tags: c#, .net, search, keyword

we're trying to create a search feature for our site.
The products are in the database and the goal would be to have the search feature use words that are in the title and description of the products inside the database. I was wondering if they where tools out there to build this kind of features. Meaning having some framework that can remove useless words from the description like 'the', 'for', 'and' etc

Without going overboard with big servers like ElastiqSearch.

Comment: what db are you guys using

Answer (score 0):

Well i am not sure what you mean? Can't you use linq or sth like that?
you can use the .Contains() that .net provides for strings.

Comment: I dont think going through thousand of products and then executing Contains on multiple fields for each product in a single request something that would result with good performance.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your DB you can use built in Full Text Index + Full Text Search to efficiently eliminate useless words.